# Showing a Result Using Cauchy's Generalised Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, cauchy-integral-formula

> Using Cauchy's generalised integral formula, show that if $f$ is an entire function and $|f(z)|\leq |z|+1$, then $f^{(k)}(0)=0$.
>
> Hence deduce that there are complex constants $a,b$ such that $f(z)=az+b$ where $|a|\leq 1$ and $|b|\leq 1$.

I have shown that $f^{(k)}(0)=0$, as for $$f^{(k)}(0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} \ dz\implies|f^{(k)}(0)|\leq\frac{n!}{R^{n-1}}+\frac{n!}{R^n}.$$  So for $n\geq 2$, $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$, by the ML lemma. Hence, by Cauchy's generalised integral formula, $$f(z)=f(0)+f'(0)z\implies a=f'(0), \ b=f(0).$$

> My question is, how do we know that $|a|\leq 1$ and $|b|\leq 1$?

**attempt**

From $|f(z)|\leq |z|+1\implies |f(0)|\leq |0|+1=1$, hence $|b|\leq 1$. Next, consider \begin{align}
f(z)&=f(0)+f'(0)z \\
f'(0)z&=f(z)-f(0) \\
|f'(0)z|&\leq |f(z)|-|f(0)| \ \ \text{(triangle inequality)} \\
|f'(0)z|&\leq |z|+1-1 \\
|f'(0)|&\leq \frac{|z|}{|z|}=1,
\end{align}
hence $|a|\leq 1$.

Comment: What do you know about $f(0)$ from $\lvert f(z)\rvert\leq\lvert z\rvert+1$?  Use the triangle inequality for the $\lvert a\rvert\leq 1$.

Comment: Thanks, I have taking this advice. Do you agree with my attempt?